# Django Rest framework cant join tables

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to fetch related data from a parent table using an API. I am trying to get the details from the operator table which has a one-to-one field with the user table.
After going through various answers I understood how to join tables but due to some reason I am unable to fetch the user data

#### serializer.py

```py
class OpDetailsSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(source="operator_details",many=False, read_only=True)
    print(user.data)
    class Meta:
        model = OperatorDetails
        fields = ('gst_no','pan','user')
```

#### models.py

```py
class OperatorDetails(models.Model):
    operator=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="operator_details",on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    pan = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=True,blank=True)
    gst_no = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True,null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.operator)
```

#### views.py

```
def view_operator_info(request):
    fields = ('operator','pan','gst_no','user')

    operator = OperatorDetails.objects.get(operator__id=request.user.id)
    serializer = OpDetailsSerializer(operator,fields=fields)
    content = {
            "status": True,
            "response": status.HTTP_200_OK,
            "message": "Operator details",
            "data":serializer.data
        }

    return Response(content)
```

Actual Output

```json
{
    "status": true,
    "response": 200,
    "message": "Operator details",
    "data": {
        "gst_no": "test",
        "pan": "test"
    }
}
```

expected Output

```
{
    "status": true,
    "response": 200,
    "message": "Operator details",
    "data": {
        "gst_no": "test",
        "pan": "test",
        "user":{
             "email":.....
              //data from user table
          }
    }
}
```

can anyone help. Thanks in advance

Comment: In your serializer.py file add operator_details in the fields list

Comment: The `user` you want is actually stored in `operator` column . So in your serializer change source to `operator` `user = UserSerializer(source="operator",many=False, read_only=True) `

Comment: @DanielButler I get an error "Field name `operator_details` is not valid for model `OperatorDetails`."

Comment: @AnuragRegmi. your solution worked. If you put an answer I will accept it

Comment: @AnuragRegmi is right I’ve created a answer using that info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your field name has to match the field on our model the other option is to use the `source` parameter.

```py
class OpDetailsSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
  user = UserSerializer(source="operator", many=False, read_only=True)
  print(user.data)
  class Meta:
    model = OperatorDetails
    fields = ('gst_no','pan','operator')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class OperatorDetails(models.Model):
operator = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="operator_details",on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
pan = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=True,blank=True)
gst_no = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True,null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.operator)

def user(Self):
    return {
        'email':self.operator.email,
        'firstname':self.first_name,
        'lastname':self.last_name
    }
```

Add the method user in your model OperatorDetails and try it.
These thing helps me lot for making custom objects in my projects and share your review after you try these so i can can also take note.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for it.

Comment: But the 'self' gives me an error. It asks me to create parameter self

Comment: @RohanAbraham   Happens